# Trying to use a custom property of a user control in a XAML storyboard animation throws a Cannot resolve TargetProperty error

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, storyboard

I'm trying to include my user control `MyControl` in a storyboard animation and animate a custom property `MyProperty` of that control. The storyboard is contained in another user control.

However, using the code below, Visual Studio Blend 2017 throws the following error in the design view of the storyboard:

**Exception: No installed components were detected.
Cannot resolve TargetProperty MyProperty on specified object.**

The problem seems to be with the custom property, since replacing it with something like `Width` works fine. Also, including `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` doesn't fix the problem.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard">

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            Storyboard.TargetName="myControl"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyProperty"
        >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <local:MyControl x:Name="myControl" Width="22" Height="22" MyProperty="0" />
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to animate a UWP (Windows 10) user control's property, type double:

```
public sealed partial class My Control : UserControl

public double MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        myProperty = value;
        Redraw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor , can you provide us the type of component that you want to animate .

Comment: @sayahimad It's a UWP (Windows 10) user control. I have updated my question.